how can i remove the white pixels between the background color and border on a button?
Between the border and background color there are some white pixels showing. The background does not fill the buttons background 100% which is annoying to look at.

I've played around with sizes of the button::before but it doesn't seem to help.


button {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

button p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "ClashGrotesk-Medium";
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
  mix-blend-mode: difference;
}

button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  border-radius: 100px;
  content: "";
  background: #000;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

button:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
<button>
  <p>Lorem Ipsum</p>
</button>




The inner absolute layer, don't need to have a radius so if we remove it it fills the gap between the two circles.


button {
  border: 2px solid #000;
  border-radius: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  color: #fff;
  pointer-events: auto;
  cursor: pointer;
  background: #e7e7e7;
  padding: 1.5rem 3rem;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
}

button p {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  font-family: "ClashGrotesk-Medium";
  font-size: 3em;
  position: relative;
}

button::before {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  content: "";
  /* border-radius: 100px; */
  background: #000;
  transition: transform 0.3s cubic-bezier(0.7, 0, 0.2, 1);
}

button:hover::before {
  transform: translate3d(0, -100%, 0);
}
<button><p>Lorem Ipsum</p></button>



